# Why does Jacoco report 0% coverage for a line that's executed by a test?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, cobertura, jacoco

Given Sample.java, a test class Sample_UT.java, SonarQube 3.7.3, why would Jacoco report 0% coverage over Sample.java while Cobertura reports 100%? The line `return new RawResponse(builder.delete(String.class, requestBody));` is clearly executed, yet Jacoco reports that it is not. My jacoco and cobertura maven profiles are shown below. Jacoco is reporting 100% on another class in the same package.

Sample.java:

```
package com.example;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class Sample {

    protected RawResponse issueQuery(WebResource.Builder builder, DataTransferObject requestBody) {
        return new RawResponse(builder.delete(String.class, requestBody));
    }
}
```

Sample_UT.java:

```
package com.example;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Sample.class, WebResource.Builder.class})
public class Sample_UT {

    @Mock
    private WebResource.Builder mockBuilder;
    @Mock
    private WebResource mockWebResource;
    @Mock
    private DataTransferObject mockTestRequestBody;

    private String testResponseBody = "response";

    @InjectMocks
    private Sample subject;

    @Test
    public void testThat_IssueQuery_ReturnsRawResponse_FromBuilder() throws Exception {
        when(mockBuilder.delete(String.class, mockTestRequestBody)).thenReturn(testResponseBody);
        assertEquals(testResponseBody, subject.issueQuery(mockBuilder, mockTestRequestBody).getBody());
    }
}
```

snippet from settings.xml:

```
<profile>
    <id>jacoco</id>
    <properties>
        <sonar.branch>JAC</sonar.branch>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/jacoco.report</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>true</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.junit.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
        <forceAnaylysis>true</forceAnaylysis>
    </properties>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>cobertura</id>
    <properties>
        <sonar.branch>COB</sonar.branch>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>cobertura</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>true</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.junit.reportsPath>target/surefire-reports</sonar.junit.reportsPath>
        <forceAnaylysis>true</forceAnaylysis>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: It's probably just a bug of Jacoco that badly monitors return statements. If Cobertura is more accurate then use this one.

Comment: In general, I agree. I'd like to wait and switch to Jacoco once the early adopters flush out the fundamental bugs. However, we need Java 1.7, and Cobertura has its own issues, which -XX:-UseSplitVerifier doesn't seem to fix for us.

Comment: However, it doesn't seem to be an issue with the return statement - if I throw a println in before the return, then Jacoco reports the return as covered, but not the println. So, it looks like it doesn't correctly report on the first line of a method in this case.

Comment: I got -XX:-UseSplitVerifier working for cobertura, so I'll stick with that for now.